# Hadoop based questions

Tags: hadoop

Can some one brief the process to take the back up of "Data node" in the hadoop cluster. The question sub divided into :

1)Is there any standard procedure to follow in order to take the back up of the hadoop cluster for each data node.

2)What is the role that played by zookeeper in taking the backup of "Data node".

3)Stopping the daemons in particular datanode that we need to take the back up and attaching an external hard disk and transferring data.. Is this is the process? can we do in order to take the back up. please let me know

Comment: I just wonder, why you want to take a back up a datanode ?

Comment: I was asked in an interview could you provide me solution for the interview question below if you got answer?

Comment: How to take a data node back up?